# Pandas' DataFrame merge unexpected values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two simple data frames:

```
a = homes_in.copy()
b = homes.copy()

a['have'] = [True,]*a.shape[0]
b['have'] = [True,]*b.shape[0]

a = a['have'].to_frame()
b = b['have'].to_frame()

print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)

a.reset_index(inplace=True)
b.reset_index(inplace=True)
idx_cols = ['State', 'RegionName']

c = pd.merge(a, b, how='outer', left_on=idx_cols, right_on=idx_cols, suffixes=['_a', '_b'])
print(c.shape)
print(sum(c['have_a']))
print(sum(c['have_b']))
```

output

```
(10730, 1)
(10592, 1)
(10730, 4)
10730
10730
```

Where `a.head()` is:

```
                    have
State RegionName        
NY    New York      True
CA    Los Angeles   True
IL    Chicago       True
PA    Philadelphia  True
AZ    Phoenix       True
```

The problem: all values in columns `have_a` and `have_b` has `True` value.

I've tried to replicate the behaviour with faked data but failed:

```
col = ['first', 'second', 'third']
a = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('a','b',1), ('a','c',1), ('a','d', 1)], columns=col)
b = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('a','b',2), ('a','c',2)], columns=col)
pd.merge(a,b,how='outer',left_on=['first','second'],right_on=['first', 'second'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are duplicates:

```
col = ['first', 'second', 'third']
a = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('a','b',True), ('a','c',True), ('a','c', True)], columns=col)
b = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('a','b',True), ('a','c',True)], columns=col)
c = pd.merge(a,b,how='outer',left_on=['first','second'],right_on=['first', 'second'])
print (a)
  first second  third
0     a      b   True
1     a      c   True <-duplicates a,c
2     a      c   True <-duplicates a,c

print (b)
  first second  third
0     a      b   True
1     a      c   True

print (c)
  first second  third_x  third_y
0     a      b     True     True
1     a      c     True     True
2     a      c     True     True
```

---

You can find duplicates:

```
print (a[a.duplicated(['first','second'], keep=False)])
  first second  third
1     a      c   True
2     a      c   True

print (b[b.duplicated(['first','second'], keep=False)])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [first, second, third]
Index: []
```

---

Solution is remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
a = a.drop_duplicates(['first','second'])
b = b.drop_duplicates(['first','second'])

c = pd.merge(a,b,how='outer',left_on=['first','second'],right_on=['first', 'second'])
print (a)
  first second  third
0     a      b   True
1     a      c   True

print (b)
  first second  third
0     a      b   True
1     a      c   True

print (c)
  first second  third_x  third_y
0     a      b     True     True
1     a      c     True     True
```

Comment: You're right. I've started digging it just after posting a question. I've made a wrong assumption about the data. My bad.

Comment: @jezrael, is there any difference in `df.loc` and `df.at`

Comment: @pyd - Yes, there is difference, `at` working only with scalar, `.loc` is more general, working with list of values too.

Comment: @pyd - You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting)